# Terminal: Deleting everything except for .nef or .jpgs

Tags: macos, mac, terminal

I am using Mountain Lion on a Mac. I want to delete all the files in a directory which do NOT end with .psd, .jpg, or .nef using Terminal. How would I do this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Bash, you can use extended globbing functions:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

Then, to delete everything but `.nef`, `.jpg` or `.psd` files:

```
rm !(*.nef|*.jpg|*.psd)
```

You can test it by using `ls` instead of `rm`. Here, the `!` inverts the match. Note that this matches directories as well, but they cannot be removed without passing the `-r` option to `rm`.

---

Another way with `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f \
! \( -name '*.nef' -or -name '*.psd' -or -name '*.jpg' \) -delete
```

Test this command by removing the `-delete` option first. Here, the `!` negates the expression in parentheses.